# We are running ubuntu on our gta 5 servers

Tags: 12.04

but we cannot seem to get the max connections to exceed 12 people help us please.
We have already tried throwing some of our billions of dollars we made from selling the game at the servers but this does not seem to appease the servers they started shooting laser beams at us and we got scared and just left our servers alone. We need help.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things you can do to remedy the situation:

- **File a kernel bug** - If there's something wrong with the servers accepting money, there's probably something wrong in the `joydev` module making it unhappy and/or angry at you. The developers there will release your fix in the next 2-3 months with the next release and your issues with connecting may be resolved.
- **Switch to using bash** - Computers don't understand physical dollar bills, they understand `$`.
- **[If you have any poo, fling it now.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgUwpb3I98M)**

Or maybe the problem will just take care of itself. The people of this age are indoctrinated with the unhealthy and violent ideas of your game and will relentlessly continue to reimburse you for using your creative talents to such an end instead of making a polygon tool for GIMP, which would actually bring light and happiness into the lives of many.

Comment: Why thank you. Its good that you mentioned that computers don't understand physical money. So now we can spend our billions on Hookers.

Comment: No, please don't! ... Install the free, open source software alternative, [`hotbabe`](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/medibuntu_free/precise/free/base/hot-babe).

Comment: Then use your billions to support yourselves and use your time to create a free software voice recognition protocol written in javascript. The chances of getting a disease are slimmer.